# Googles multilingual xml sitemap example is not rendering correctly

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap

I'm implementing a multiple language sitemap and the xml example that Google gives is showing plain text when visiting in browser

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/english/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="http://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="http://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="http://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions?hl=en&visit_id=637599535586353543-2604365232&rd=2#sitemap

Why isn't xml rendering correctly in browser?

Comment: Can you share a image where google showing your XML as plain text?

Comment: @LovekeshKumar  https://snipboard.io/MuZcpe.jpg  this is how the google sitemap example  looks in when visited in browser

Answer (score 0):

This can be the problem with `content-type` which you are providing in the headers of the file.

Content-type for sitemap file should be `text/xml` or `sitemap/xml`.

[image]

So first check your `content-type` in headers and change this to the correct type.